# Does "Have a bearing on" also mean "impact"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Almost all definitions which I've found about this phrase describes it as a way to say that something is related to something else but the more I search the more I believe that it more often means "impact" or "Influence" rather than "relation".

Could someone please help me to understand this phrase?

Comment: Generally I would think it means both

Comment: If it helps, here's a more "precise" usage where it would be a bit silly to replace *have a bearing on* with *influence, affect*: [This explains why archaeologists are so careful to record the depth at which objects are found— the depth usually **has a bearing on the age** of the find](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has+a+bearing+on+the+planet%27s%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22has+a+bearing+on+the+age%22). Obviously the age is whatever it is, so it can't be affected/changed by something like "the depth".

Answer (score 1):

***Does "have a bearing on" also mean "impact"?*** No.

***Can someone help me to understand this phrase?*** I shall try.

*Having a bearing on* an object is an effect of sharing a trait with a demonstrable effect; *impact* on the other hand, is a cause to an effect upon another object.

Let's take @FumbleFingers' example:

> This explains why archeologists are so careful to record the depth at which objects are found - the *depth* usually ***has a bearing on*** the age of the find.

The depth of the earth in a given location is an effect of the conditions at the time it was deposited. An archeological artifact deposited at a given depth in a given location is an effect of the conditions at the time it was deposited. Thus the depth of the earth is *having a bearing on* the age of the find because the age of the earth at that depth and the age of the find should be the same.

So, to sum up:

- ***Impact*** causes an effect on an object
- ***Having a bearing on*** is a demonstrable effect of a trait shared between objects.

Answer (score 0):

"bearing" as a noun has several meanings. OALD, 8th edition, has "to have some bearing on sth" and says "to have bearing"  in this formulation has the meaning of relevance.

The online version of OALD has another explanation with relation or influence, which I think is not so clear.